# How can I store Brie for a long period?

Tags: storage-method, cheese, food-preservation, storage, brie

There's a semi-local creamery that makes the loveliest Brie I've ever had. It's priced quite reasonably but the shipping costs more than the cheese itself, so it's a little impractical. I bought three rounds a while ago, but by the time I made it through the first two, the third had gone mouldy. Is there a way to store Brie over an extended period of time? I'd love to get a half-dozen rounds and portion them out over time.

Comment: Freezing will definitely change the texture and flavor, and I'd say that beats the purpose of buying such great cheese. I'd rather buy less of it and enjoy it as much as possible while fresh...

Answer (score 2):

IMO, It it not the best situation.

Freeze them up.

It will not be as good as the unfrozen cheese.

Cut them in manageable portions, wrap them up in plastic film and put in freezer bag, freeze as quickly as possible.

For the cheese you want to keep in the fridge, I suggest finding cheese wrapper and wrap the cheese in it while keeping them in the fridge (you can also use wax paper)